# Run a "light" preprocessor for GCC

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to run the [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) preprocessor, but only for user-defined macros?

I have a few one-liners and some `#ifdef`, etc. conditionals, and I want to see what my code looks like when just those are expanded.

As it is, the includes get expanded, my `fprintf(stderr)`s turn into `fprintf(((__getreeent())->_stderr)`, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Call `cpp` directly, e.g.

```
$ cat >foo.c <<EOF
#define FOO
#ifdef FOO
foo is defined
#else
foo is not defined
#endif
EOF

$ cpp foo.c
# 1 "foo.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "foo.c"


foo is defined
```

Of course, if you include any headers then those will be included in the output. One way to avoid that might be to just `grep -v` out the lines with `#include`s (or perhaps just ones with `#include <` and allow `#include "`). Or you could specify the `-nostdinc` option to remove just standard includes (but possibly leave in local libraries unless you specify include paths so that they won't be found) - this would warn about missing headers, though.

Edit: Or use the preprocessor itself to make the inclusion of headers conditional, wrap them in something like `#ifndef TESTING_PREPROCESSOR` and use `-DTESTING_PREPROCESSOR`.

Comment: +1 - The tip for putting the `#include` lines in an `#if` section is one of those simple yet effective things that might not occur to someone until a bunch of other effort was wasted trying other more complicated things.

Answer (score 5):

```
cpp -nostdinc program.c
```

Answer (score 3):

One may use tools like unifdef, unifdefall — remove preprocessor conditionals from code

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc  -E inputfile.c > outputfile.c
```

outputfile.c will have your preprocessed code, but all macros will be expanded.

I find this trick very useful when debugging compilation of large systems with tons of includes, compiler flags, and makefile variables. It will expose include files that don't have header guards, and a bunch of other problems too.

Comment: Isn't that just the standard way to run the preprocessor? How does this answer the question? Presumably the OP wants a non-standard behaviour(?).

Comment: This is the standard way. If your program is heavy on user-defined macros, and light on non-user-defined macros, then the user-defined macros will be easy to spot. by running a diff of inputfile.c and outputfile.c.  In many cases, gcc -E is good enough, though definitely perfect in detecting "only" user-defined macros. And it is a lot faster than using the perfect methods described in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want macro expansions and skip the `#include` handling, you can try this [repo](https://github.com/smwikipedia/pcpp). It is a fork of the original [pcpp](https://github.com/ned14/pcpp). I added a `--no-include` option to skip the handling of `#include` directive. All other macros will be processed based on your marco input to `pcpp`.