# Run preprocessor only but with only for certain statements

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have a number of debug statements defined in a program, and I want to be able to make a copy of the source without these statements.

In order to do this I first looked at GCC's -E command line argument, which only runs the preprocessor, however this did far more than I wanted, expanding the included files and adding #line statements.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
    #define debug( s ) puts ( s );
#else
    #define debug( s )
#endif

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    debug( "Foo" )

    puts( "Hello, World!" );

    return 0;
}
```

I'd want this to be processed to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{


    puts( "Hello, World!" );

    return 0;
}
```

I could then tidy that up with something like astyle and no manual work would be needed to get exactly what I want.

Is there a directive I'm missing for GCC or is there a tool capable of doing this?

Comment: Also, consider finding a regex that matches these lines and delete them in your editor

Comment: You could write a very simple parser and overwrite file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `-E` is not helping, then try using `-fdump-tree-all` and if you don't see what you want the that is not-available-in (or) not-provided-by [`GCC`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html).

OTOH, this question has been discussed in SO as follows, please refer the below to get some ideas.

1. [Can gcc output C code after preprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900870/can-gcc-output-c-code-after-preprocessing)
2. [How do I see a C/C++ source file after preprocessing in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing)

Hope it helps!

---

Hi Mat,

I saw your comment to @nos. But I have one such script handy and so sharing it with you. You can try reading my answer for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742418/avoid-the-preprocessing-of-includes/8742815#8742815)

Copy the below code in a file, say `convert.sh`. Assign execute permission to that file, `chmod +x convert.sh` and run it as follows:

```
$./convert.sh <filename>.c
$cat filename.c.done
```

The `<filename>.c.done` will have what you need!

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 1 || ! -f $1 ]] ; then
    echo "Invalid args / Check file "
    exit 
fi

file_name=$1

grep '^\s*#\s*include' $file_name > /tmp/include.c
grep -Pv '^\s*#\s*include\b' $file_name > /tmp/code.c
gcc -E /tmp/code.c | grep -v ^# > /tmp/preprocessed.c
cat /tmp/include.c > $file_name.done
cat /tmp/preprocessed.c >> $file_name.done
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As already mentioned, I know about -E, but it does too much preprocessing, as I only want one statement resolved. So no, this question has not been discussed before as far as I know. I'll try -fdump-tree-all, but as I understand it, that is for outputting the AST after various high level optimisations.

Comment: @Mat This is a good question and deserves a +1.. so +1 from me! If you come across an answer, please do share it!

Comment: comment out the #includes and other macros in your file, then run gcc -E

Comment: As mentioned by @nos comment out the `#includes` and run `gcc -E mac.c | sed '/^\#/d'`. It works! .. I guess writing a script using `grep` to comment out the `#includes` is not a big deal!

Comment: @nos, since that's as good an answer as I've seen about this, would you mind writing it as an answer in it's own right so I can mark this as answered. Having done more research that is the only way I know of to do it effectively.

Comment: That addition is perfect, so thank you. I already had a similar thing going, but doing it a bit more manually.

Comment: There is an issue with this script if some of the includes are conditionally included themselves. This will include them regardless.

Answer (score 5):

`gcc -E -nostdinc test.c` produces

```
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"
# 9 "test.c"
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{


    puts( "Hello, World!" );

    return 0;
}
```

and an error to stderr

```
test.c:1:19: error: no include path in which to search for stdio.h
```

You can easily filter out the # lines ... and re-add the includes.

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct way to do that with the gcc preprocessor, though if you only include system headers, you might have some luck with `gcc -E -nostdinc`.

However, you can comment out the `#include` directives, and other preprocessor directives you don't want processed, and run the code through the preprocessor (`gcc -E` or `cpp`)  , that way only the macro you want expanded(the ones not commented out) gets expanded.

Answer (score 2):

One may use tools like unifdef, unifdefall — remove preprocessor conditionals from code. ([Run a "light" preprocessor for GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615931/gcc-run-light-preprocessor))

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but it does have an answer now. The "C Partial Preprocessor" does exactly this.

http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/cppp.html

For reference, if someone else still wonders (I did and found this page).

Answer (score 0):

Also `cpp -P <file> [outputfile]`

*a.txt :*

```
file: __FILE__
#ifdef X
"X" has been defined
#endif
```

---

cpp -P -DX a.txt