# How to expand macros only as a preprocessing step to a C++ file

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am looking to expand only macros in my C++ code.
I understand that -E option runs only preprocessor, but I am not looking for complete preprocessed output. All I want is a C++ code with all macros expanded.

I need to submit this code to a analyser, who don't understand macros. But a preprocessed code will defeat the purpose, as it will add lot of third party code (via include files) to the code.

Comment: Why exactly can't you use the `-E` switch? Or use `cpp src_file`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a "light" preprocessor for GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615931/run-a-light-preprocessor-for-gcc)

Comment: I had same issue and never found a solution, right now I delegated most of the work of Macros to a external tool (Cmake) so that I have minimal macro that don't really need expansion to get debugged. your best bet is having code where include files are really mimimal (in example using Pimpl idiom or pure virtual classes greatly reduces number of inclusions). I think certain IDES just show expanded macro if you put mouse over it

Comment: @cad That would strip comments and evaluate all `#include` and `#if` directives as well.

Comment: Do you need to keep `#ifdef`s too?

Comment: The preprocessor outputs information about where the include files are. In GCC it looks like this: `# 1 "<string>"`, where `1` is the line number. Microsofts preprocessor, AFAIK, includes `#line` directives. Maybe you can try and filter the preprocessor output based on that information.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want macro expansions and skip the `#include` handling, this may help: https://github.com/ned14/pcpp/pull/34